# Rails query with multiple conditions on the same field

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models, `Recipes` and `Skills`. In this scenario, a skill is a cooking technique, like baking, frying, etc. So each recipe has a certain set of associated skills.

I want to search all the recipes like this:

1. Find all recipes that use any given set of skills (e.g. `Baking` OR `Frying` OR both)
   **EDIT:** This should NOT return recipes that require a skill that wasn't in the search query - e.g. If I search for skills [1, 2] I don't want a recipe that uses skills [1, 2, 4] or any other superset.
2. If you add a new skill to the search, return just the additional recipes (e.g. if you add `Boiling` to the previous query of `Baking` or `Frying`, how many NEW recipes can you now cook?)

I currently have this working in Rails using plain old Ruby methods:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :practices
  has_many :skills, through: :practices

  def self.find_recipes_that_require_any_of_these_skills(*known_skill_ids)
    self.select do |recipe|
      recipe.skill_ids.all? do |skill_id|
        known_skill_ids.include?(skill_id)
      end
    end
  end

  # calls the above method twice, once with the new skill and once without
  # and subtracts one result from the other
  def self.find_newly_unlocked_recipes(*prior_skill_ids, new_skill_id)
    self.find_recipes_that_require_any_of_these_skills(*(prior_skill_ids + [new_skill_id])) - self.find_recipes_that_require_any_of_these_skills(*prior_skill_ids)
  end
end
```

In Rails console: `Recipe.find_recipes_that_require_any_of_these_skills(1,4)`
returns all the Recipe objects for skill 1, skill 4, or skills 1 & 4.

But this is inefficient because it generates a SQL query for every single recipe in my database.

**How can I write these queries the ActiveRecord/SQL way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two queries to DB:

```
def self.find_recipes_that_require_any_of_these_skills(*known_skill_ids)
  Recipe.joins(:skills)
        .merge(Skill.where(id: known_skill_ids))
        .where("recipes.id NOT IN (?)", Recipe.joins(:skills).merge(Skill.where("skills.id NOT IN (?)", known_skill_ids)).uniq.pluck(:id)).uniq
end
```

Comment: This almost works. Currently it returns duplicates - if you search for skills [1,2] and a recipe uses both skills, it will return that recipe twice.

Comment: Now it works! It's still several different SQL queries... but hey, it's a constant rather than scaling with the number of DB entries. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def self.find_recipes_that_require_any_of_these_skills(*known_skill_ids)
  self.includes(:skills).where(skills: { id: known_skill_ids })
end
```

Comment: As an aside: if I wanted to find recipes that use ONLY a given set of skills (say, 1 AND 2, but not any others, and not just 1, and not just 2) - how would I write that query?

Comment: My solution solves your problem by just single SQL query (see my answer)

Comment: UPDATE: After a bit of checking, this actually doesn't work. If I search for skills [1,4] then I want to get back recipes that use [1], [4], or [1,4]. I don't want to get back recipes that use [1,4,5] or any other superset of skills. Your answer currently returns the superset, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The following method uses just three sql queries in total to create a collection of recipies

```
array_of_skills=["cooking","frying",...]
skills=Skill.where('name in (?)',array_of_skills).map(&:id)
```

Up to here you already have, so you might need just this:

```
practices=Practice.where('skill_id in (?)',skills).map(&:recipe_id)
recipes=Recipe.where('id in (?)', practices)
```

Maybe there is a better way, but I don't think there would be something with much less sql

Comment: Why not Recipes.joins(:practice).where(practice:{skill_id:skills})

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `has_many :skills, through: :practices` - your Practices table should have both `recipe_id` and `skills_id` columns.

`previous_recipe_ids = Recipe.joins(:practices).where('practices.skill_id in (?)', prior_skills_ids).map(&:id)
Recipe.joins(:practices).where('practices.skill_id = (?) and recipes.recipe_id not in (?)', new_skill_id, previous_recipe_ids)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that your **find_recipes_that_require_any_of_these_skills** method isn't correct. It returns recipes that have all of the known_skill, not any.

So, the ActiveRecord/SQL way:

Known skills:

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base

    #known skills
    scope :known_skills, -> { where(id: known_skill_ids) }

    #not known skills
    scope :not_known_skills, -> { where("skills.id NOT IN (?)", known_skill_ids) }
```

Recipes that have any of known skills:

```
Recipe.joins(:skills).merge(Skill.known_skills)
```

Newly_unlocked_recipes:

```
Recipe.joins(:skills).merge(Skill.not_known_skills).where("skills.id = ?", new_skill_id)
```

Comment: My original method `find_recipes_that_require_any_of_these_skills` does return exactly what I want it to return. If I search for skills [1,4] then I want to get back recipes that use [1], [4], or [1,4]. I **don't** want to get back recipes that use [1,4,5] or any other superset of skills. Your answer currently returns the superset, which is not what I'm looking for.