# Ransack: how to find records that have a combination of related records using AND condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Suppose I had a `BlogPost` object that `has_many :tags`. Now I want find Blog posts that have 2 or more specific tags associated.

For my search I use ransack, and I want to find all Blog posts that have Tags with Id 5 & 7.

My request looks like this:

```
"q":{
   "active_tags_tag_id_in":[5,7],
}
```

Now the problem is, this will give me any post with either tag 5 or tag 7 applied.

What I want however, is that both tag 5 and tag 7 should be applied.

So switch from OR to AND logic. I can't find anything in ransack documentation that tells me how to do this.

Comment: I am not aware of a ransack predicate that will do this for you but the following questions/answers might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869962/activerecord-how-to-chain-multiple-condition-on-a-join-table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397270/rails-5-query-association-must-comply-with-multiple-conditions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673106/rails-query-with-multiple-conditions-on-the-same-field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107021/query-in-activerecord-for-objects-that-contain-one-or-more-ids-from-multiple-arr

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Ransack hasn't good documentation for advanced search but there is Ransack demo example site on Heroku:

http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/users/advanced_search

You can use it as some kind of sandbox. If you try to experiment there, you will notice that there is such a thing as group conditions in Ransack

To create group you need to define `g` param inside standard `q` param. To define AND/OR condition in the group you need to define nested `m` param

Finally your request params will be look something like this

```
"q": {
  "g": [
    {
      "m": "and",
      "active_tags_tag_id_eq": 5
    },
    {
      "m": "and",
      "active_tags_tag_id_eq": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work. The SQL generated would be akin to `SELECT * FROM blog_posts INNER JOIN active_tags ON active_tags.blog_post_id = blog_posts.id WHERE active_tags.tag_id = 5 AND active_tags.tag_id = 7`. Since each "ActiveTag" only has 1 `tag_id` this condition cannot be met. Also ransack includes a predicate for what you proposed e.g. `active_tags_eq_all: [5,7]`. This predicate is not documented because it doesn't make logical sense that something could equal multiple somethings.